# Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I updated my android studio to 3.0 I got the error DexArchiveBuilderException while gradle building

The error was  showing these files

> Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to
>   process E:\Android\Android
>   Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle-core\2.2.0\gradle-core-2.2.0.jar
>
> Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error
>   while dexing com/android/build/gradle/shrinker/AbstractShrinker.class
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:
>
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to
>   process E:\Android\Android
>   Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle-core\2.2.0\gradle-core-2.2.0.jar

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.win7.koboclicks"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //Circle ImageView
    //Circle Layout
    //Retrofit 2.0
    //Glide Library
    implementation project(':libraries:UniversalImageLoader-Library')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.github.francoiscampbell:circlelayout:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: I think this is an Android 3.1 and gradle 3.1 problem. I didn't have such problems until i had to update to gradle 3.1 because I use Android 3.1

Comment: yeah, switching back to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0` seemed to work for me

Comment: No, facing same problem in com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0

Comment: Still I'm using Android Studio 3.0 (Stable release) only,But I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Any solution? Same problem here

Comment: Same problem here!

Comment: same problem here :(

Comment: Fixed for me with `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'` Version 3.1.2 doesn't work

Comment: I encountered this problem with AS 3.0, tools 3.0.0, and gradle 4.3.1. Solution was to change gradle to 4.2.1

Comment: anyone found a solution for this?